# PathCchAppend and relative paths

Tags: c++

When using PathCchAppend with a relative path referring to some parent

```
"..\..\folder1\" + "folder2"
```

the result is

```
"folder1\folder2\"
```

instead of

```
"..\..\folder1\folder2\"
```

Instead of making my own function, is there a better method/option to append paths in 
PathCchAppendEx and PathCchCombine have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to combine two relative paths with one of the functions of this family. I'd get an absolute path using GetCurrentDirectory() or GetModuleFileName() (depending on you case) and combining it with the first path and then would combine the result with the second. Usually you always have some point where you can build an absolute path to start with.